# I'm trying to count the number of letters in a word and then print the word typed by the user that many times

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print ("Enter a word")
word = str(input())
total = len(word)
count = 0
while (total > count):
    count+1
    print(word)
```

Everything works up to the while loop, when I type in something it just repeats the word forever.

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
count = count + 1
```

or

```
count += 1
```

Dont update count with count+1;

Comment: Only answer actually explaining the error of OP's code. +1

Answer (score 2):

A more pythonic way is to use a for loop :

```
print ("Enter a word")
word = str(input())
total = len(word)

for i in range(total-1):
    print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use the multiplication of strings:

```
print((word+'\n')*len(word))
```